# How to Remove an object from a triple nested document in a MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I have a Wikidata collection in MongoDB with documents of following structure:

```
{
   id: 178
   type: "something"
   claims: {
      P1{
         [0]: {
           id: "234"
           obj:{...}
         }
         [1]: {
           id: "456"
           obj:{}
         }
         [2]: {
           id: "789"
           obj:{...}          
         }
      }
      P2: {
         [list of objects]
      }
      P3: {
         [list of objects]
      }
   }
}
```

I'm trying to iterate over all items under `claims` (i.e., `P1, P2, P3`) and delete certain objects under them (e.g., `id:234`)

In other words how to delete the nested object with `id: "234"` for example?

Comment: Try `db.colletion_name.update(   { },   { $pull: { "claims.P1": { id: "234" } } } )`

Answer (score 0):

Under `P1`, `P2`, and `P3` fields are nested arrays.

As @veeram commented, an update query with the `$pull` operator is ideal for this scenario.

```
condition = {'id': '234'}
field_val = {'claims.{}'.format(field): condition for field in ('P1', 'P2', 'P3')}

db.collection_name.update({}, {$pull: field_val })
```